# php arrays in external js file

Tags: php, javascript, external-js

I have this change request to move all my inline javascript to an external file. I tried a simple copy-paste to a new file, but no luck. I'm getting error at the following line:
     `var grp_list = <?php echo json_encode($arr_grp); ?>;`    and
      `url: "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`
I have atleast 20 such occurrences. How do I replace these php variables in external javascript??
I checked lot of forums but did not find any solution.

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can't pass the PHP variables directly to an external JS file without some work in PHP generating the files, then sending custom headers to treat the file as JavaScript (edit: see post by **Marcovecchio** if this sounds like a likely solution)... a quick solution is to pass the variables inline so they are global, then use them inside your external file. This will allow for the majority of your JavaScript to be in external files, but also allow you to pass your variables from PHP to JS.

By no means is this the best solution, but it's more than likely the easiest to get working.

Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var grp_list = <?php echo json_encode($arr_grp); ?>;
    var url = "<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>
```

Comment: aah this worked, i tried it before, but it did not work back then.. anyway.. i'm glad it's working now.. i hope this type of change wont hamper performance? Do we have to give this `<script type="text/javascript" src="external.js"></script>` in html head as well as body?

Comment: You just need to make sure your external files come after the variables, it can be in the `<head>` or in the `<body>`, doesn't need to be in both

Answer (score 2):

Well, you have JavaScript dinamically "assembled" in your PHP script. The easiest solution is to forget about translating the variables. Instead, put all JS code, including the PHP portions, in a PHP file which will pretend to be a JS file, using a custom header. So, your "JavaScript" file will be like this:

```
<?php
  // Send a custom header, so that it will be interpreted as a js file.     
  header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
?>

JavaScript and PHP mixed code will go in here, with no modifications
```

Save this file as something like "javascript.php". Then, in your main HTML or PHP file, include it as:

```
<script src="javascript.php"></script>
```

That's it! The javascript.php file will be interpreted as a PHP file in the server and retrieved by the browser as JS. Only pay attetion on the kind of processing the PHP in the javascript file does: it may depend on the context you had in the main script, so additional adjustments may be necessary.